# Is there a way to denormalize data in the resultset of an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table Students as follows:

```
SNO    NAME   SUBJECT   MARKS
-----------------------------    
1      HARWI   HINDI     75
2      SHWETA  ENGLISH   80
3      RUDRA   MATHS     90
4      HARWI   MATHS     60
5      MANVI   GK        89
6      RUDRA   HINDI     98
7      SHWETA  MATHS     67
```

I need output like this:

```
1   HARWI     HINDI   75
              MATHS   60
2   MANVI     GK      89
3   RUDRA     HINDI   98
              MATHS   90
4   SHWETA    ENGLISH 80
              MATHS   67
```

I DO NOT WANT TO USE concatenation operator `||`

Are there standard functions in Oracle which can help me achieve this result set?

Comment: there's nothing to do with concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions `row_number()` and `dense_rank()`:

```
with cte as (
  select s.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by marks desc) as rn
  from students s
)
select 
  case when c.rn > 1 then null else dense_rank() over (order by c.name) end as rn,
  case when c.rn > 1 then null else name end as name, 
  subject, marks
from cte c
order by c.name, c.rn
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2dad3930fc58f0ae0a40b808ffabf723).
Results:

```
>   RN | NAME   | SUBJECT | MARKS
> ---: | :----- | :------ | ----:
>    1 | HARWI  | HINDI   |    75
>      |        | MATHS   |    60
>    2 | MANVI  | GK      |    89
>    3 | RUDRA  | HINDI   |    98
>      |        | MATHS   |    90
>    4 | SHWETA | ENGLISH |    80
>      |        | MATHS   |    67
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `analytical function` as following:

```
select case when lag(name) over(partition by name order by marks) is null then dr end as sno,
case when lag(name) over(partition by name order by marks) is null then name end as name,
subject,
marks
from (
  select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by t.name desc) as dr
  from students t -- dense rank is used to give numbers to the student - sno
)
order by dr;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you , solution worked and expected result was obtained.